# How do I execute a linux command in Jmeter and save the output to a variable?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I have tried using beanshell and groovey and OS proccess sampler but none seem to work for me.

any suggestions would be appreciated

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Post processor to [OS Process sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), as [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and use Regular Expression as `(\w+)` to get output

This is assuming you left `Standard output` empty which will return the output in response data

> Standard output (stdout Name of output file for standard output (STDOUT). If omitted, output is captured and returned as the response data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) like

```
vars.put('foo', 'your_command_here'.execute().text)
```

Demo:
[image: JMeter Groovy Execution of Command into Variable]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: It works when i do the echo command. However, if I try and use another command that works on terminal (just returns 0 as an output) then  JSR223 Sampler returns nothing. 2018-02-22 13:29:14,057 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: foo variable value:

Comment: I am using | grep so not sure if that makes it not work?

Comment: Pipe (`|` symbol) is a part of shell interpreter so my expectation is that you need to go for something like  `vars.put('foo', '/bin/bash -c your_command | grep your_pattern).execute().text)`

Comment: That does not seem to work, it does not return anything :S